# Arrow over notes

Tags: sheet-music, violin

[image]

In this music for the violin, the strange sign on top of both E-flat on measure 74 confused me, as I have no idea what it is, and it is not exclusive to just E-flats, as it is also present in an F and a B previously in the sheet-music.

[image]

The Piece is Arlington Sketches. What can it mean?

Comment: If it's in some kind of tutorial, is it simply pointing out the rule about accidentals? The rule that says even though the low E has a flat sign, the high E ALSO needs one?

Comment: What piece is this from? As it has “Violin I” as a header, I’m guessing it’s **not** from a tutor book...?

Comment: Please post the F'n'B part - if they're # or b then Neil's answer works.

Comment: No, it was not from a book. It was an orchestral piece, and I added the F and B parts, is you would need it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The arrows could refer to the finger positions. The first E-flat is low 1st finger. The second one low 4th. If the F you mention is on the E-string it is low 1st, if it is on the D-string it is low 2nd. And so forth.

It is common in violin sheet music to indicate low finger positions with down arrows, especially in music with pedagogical intention.

EDIT:
Now that the OP has posted another screenshot it is even more clear that it is in fact low fingering that is the matter as I described above. All those notes which have a down arrow are low finger positions on the violin.

Answer (score 2):

Beginners of violin playing are used to learn first little melodies in major on the E, A and D string: the motifs like DoReMiDo will be (analog to Guitar frets) 0,2,4,0.

The arrows above F, Bb and Eb are assigning that the finger position is now lower compared by F#, B and E.

So I agree with Lars Peter Schultz, additionally trying to show the pedagogical intention as reminder of the natural F and the flattened B and E.

Answer (score 0):

The down- or up-arrow is often pencilled in by performers to indicate intonation (as in, "this note should be played lower [higher] in pitch than feels natural"). I've never seen it actually used in printed music, but that would be consistent with the context of those four notes in the example.

Answer (score -1):

It is probably a reminder of the notation rule that a flat at the same pitch lasts for the whole measure, but any other octaves of the same note have the pitch indicated with their own accidentals.

Comment: It can not be that, because the note F is also mentioned and that one has no accidental. Anyway check out my answer.

Comment: @LarsPeterSchultz - OP says the F and B are previous - not on that screenshot. The question is about arrows. There are no arrows over any other notes there!

Comment: @Tim yes the question is about arrows and OP indicates that there are arrows above F and B previous (not on the screenshot). I actually wonder whether he means B-flat, because that would make sense regarding the arrows. F and B-flat requires a low finger position but not B natural.

Comment: Now that the OP has posted another screenshot it is clear that he meant B-flat and not B.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest it's telling you which string to use. In the passage that starts D up to A, you'd play those on the open D and A strings.

For the following descending G F E you *could* then switch back to the D string - **but** you'd quickly need to change down to the G string to play the C.

So in the first passage the down arrow means that instead of the D string, use the **G** string for the next few notes. You can then play the descending passage G F E C without needing to change string part way through.

In general, the down arrow means "skip a string" to play the next note.

Comment: That would be so far from normal notations in violin sheet music that it would require a forword explaining the matter. And if such a forword existed the OP would not need to ask the question.